# Setting UV Coordinates Of Texture In Metal Programmatically Deforms Texture

Tags: ios, swift, metal

In my project I am creating Vertexes programmatically which means I am filling
following struct with data I am creating in application.

```
struct Vertex{
var position: SIMD3<Float>
var color: SIMD4<Float>
var textCoors: SIMD2<Float>
}
```

My objects are simple they are planes consist of two triangles.

I am creating texture coordinates with following code;

pI is the plane index. My object consists of certain number of planes.

l is the index of corner positions of planes.

It works fine if my planes are square or rectangle it places texture seamlessly.

[image]

But if my quadrilateral corner coordinates are not symmetrical.

[image]

(Square and rectangle is special case of quadrilateral)
Texture is deforming.

I could not find fine solution I have some ideas like making may plane with many
small squares but it feels crappy There should be better solution.

```
func textureRip(pI: Int, l: Int, vertex: [[SIMD3<Float>]]) -> SIMD2<Float> {
        
        var textCoor0 = SIMD2<Float>()
        
        // We have this ratio because metalview coordinate system 2x2 unit size
        // from -1 to 1 for both x and y. Texture coordinate sistem is 1 unit wide and
        // unit height. (0 to 1). So metal view twice as much bigger.
        let ratio:Float = 2
        
        // We are adding 1 to metal view values because its values begins
        // from -1 so we are shifting its coordinate system to texture coordinate
        // system along wiht ratio.
        let x0  =  (vertex[pI][0].x + 1) / ratio
        let x   =  (vertex[pI][1].x + 1) / ratio
        
        // We are using "1 -" because texture coordinate sistem origin is
        // at the top left corner and metal view coordinate system at center.
        // in that case texture look upside down so we are turning it using "1-".
        let y0  = 1 - (vertex[pI][0].y + 1) / ratio
        let y   = 1 - (vertex[pI][2].y + 1) / ratio
        
        
        if l == 0 {
            
            textCoor0 = SIMD2<Float>(x0, y0)
            
        } else if l == 1 {
            
            textCoor0 = SIMD2<Float>(x, y0)
            
        } else if l == 2 {
            
            textCoor0 = SIMD2<Float>(x, y)
            
        } else {
            
            textCoor0 = SIMD2<Float>(x0, y)
            
        }
        
        
        return textCoor0
    }
```

Comment: How do you expect the texture to look on a trapezoid?

Comment: @Spo1ler I think I answered your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my mistake as generally it is.

Instead of using four corner of quadrilateral I has been using two corner data of it, as if it is going to be always square or rectangle.

I revised func and it is not optimized as you can see I am just experimenting with Metal to see what I can do with it.

```
func textureRip(pI: Int, l: Int, vertex: [[SIMD3<Float>]]) -> SIMD2<Float> {
        
        var textCoor = SIMD2<Float>()
        
        // We have this ratio because metalview coordinate system 2x2 unit size
        // from -1 to 1 for both x and y. Texture coordinate sistem is 1 unit wide and
        // unit height. (0 to 1). So metal view twice as much bigger.
        let ratio:Float = 2
        
        // We are adding 1 to metal view values because its values begins
        // from -1 so we are shifting its coordinate system to texture coordinate
        // system along wiht ratio.
        let x1  =  (vertex[pI][0].x + 1) / ratio
        let x2  =  (vertex[pI][1].x + 1) / ratio
        
        let x3  =  (vertex[pI][2].x + 1) / ratio
        let x4  =  (vertex[pI][3].x + 1) / ratio
        
         
        
        // We are using "1 -" because texture coordinate sistem origin is
        // at the top left corner and metal view coordinate system at center.
        // in that case texture look upside down so we are turning it using "1-".
        let y1  = 1 - (vertex[pI][0].y + 1) / ratio
        let y2  = 1 - (vertex[pI][1].y + 1) / ratio
        
        let y3  = 1 - (vertex[pI][2].y + 1) / ratio
        let y4  = 1 - (vertex[pI][3].y + 1) / ratio
        
        
        
        if l == 0 {
            
            textCoor = SIMD2<Float>(x1, y1)
            
        } else if l == 1 {
            
            textCoor = SIMD2<Float>(x2, y2)
            
        } else if l == 2 {
            
            textCoor = SIMD2<Float>(x3 , y3)
            
        } else {
            
            textCoor = SIMD2<Float>(x4, y4)
            
        }
        
        
        return textCoor
    }
```

And as it can be seen, my test image looks good as texture.
Every quadrilateral is separate object actually and can be moved around independently.

[image]